# Tensorflow: Confusion regarding the adam optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm confused regarding as to how the adam optimizer actually works in tensorflow.

The way I read the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#AdamOptimizer), it says that the learning rate is changed every gradient descent iteration.

But when I call the function I give it a learning rate. And I don't call the function to let's say, do one epoch (implicitly calling # iterations so as to go through my data training). I call the function for each batch explicitly like

```
for epoch in epochs
     for batch in data
          sess.run(train_adam_step, feed_dict={eta:1e-3})
```

So my eta cannot be changing. And I'm not passing a time variable in. Or is this some sort of generator type thing where upon session creation `t` is incremented each time I call the optimizer?

Assuming it is some generator type thing and the learning rate is being invisibly reduced: How could I get to run the adam optimizer without decaying the learning rate? It seems to me like [RMSProp](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#RMSPropOptimizer) is basically the same, the only thing I'd have to do to make it equal (learning rate disregarded) is to change the hyperparameters `momentum` and `decay` to match `beta1` and `beta2` respectively. Is that correct?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I find the documentation quite clear, I will paste here the algorithm in pseudo-code:

**Your parameters**:

- `learning_rate`: between 1e-4 and 1e-2 is standard
- `beta1`: 0.9 by default
- `beta2`: 0.999 by default
- `epsilon`: 1e-08 by default

  > The default value of 1e-8 for epsilon might not be a good default in general. For example, when training an Inception network on ImageNet a current good choice is 1.0 or 0.1.

---

**Initialization:**

```py
m_0 <- 0 (Initialize initial 1st moment vector)
v_0 <- 0 (Initialize initial 2nd moment vector)
t <- 0 (Initialize timestep)
```

`m_t` and `v_t` will keep track of a **moving average** of the gradient and its square, for each parameters of the network. (So if you have 1M parameters, Adam will keep in memory 2M more parameters)

---

**At each iteration `t`, and for each parameter of the model**:

```py
t <- t + 1
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)

m_t <- beta1 * m_{t-1} + (1 - beta1) * gradient
v_t <- beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) * gradient ** 2
variable <- variable - lr_t * m_t / (sqrt(v_t) + epsilon)
```

---

Here `lr_t` is a bit different from `learning_rate` because for early iterations, the moving averages have not converged yet so we have to normalize by multiplying by `sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)`. When `t` is high (`t > 1./(1.-beta2)`), `lr_t` is almost equal to `learning_rate`

---

To answer your question, you just need to pass a **fixed learning rate**, keep `beta1` and `beta2` default values, maybe modify `epsilon`, and Adam will do the magic :)

---

#### Link with RMSProp

Adam with `beta1=1` is equivalent to RMSProp with `momentum=0`. The argument `beta2` of Adam and the argument `decay` of RMSProp are the same.

However, RMSProp does not keep a moving average of the gradient. But it can maintain a momentum, like MomentumOptimizer.

#### A detailed description of rmsprop.

- maintain a moving (discounted) average of the square of gradients
- divide gradient by the root of this average
- (can maintain a momentum)

---

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
v_t <- decay * v_{t-1} + (1-decay) * gradient ** 2
mom = momentum * mom{t-1} + learning_rate * gradient / sqrt(v_t + epsilon)
variable <- variable - mom
```

Comment: I hadn't realized that the learning rate was not being decayed but instead normalized. So thanks for that.

Comment: I see. Yeah there's a difference between keeping a momentum and keeping a moving average of the gradient. Thank you.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't it `sqrt(1 - beta1^t) / (1 - beta2^t)`?

Comment: These values are meant to be such that if `gradient` is constant at all iterations, the update to `variable` is also constant.

Answer (score 2):

RMS_PROP and ADAM both have adaptive learning rates .

**The basic RMS_PROP**

```
cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
x += - learning_rate * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + eps)
```

You can see originally this has two parameters **decay_rate & eps**

Then we can add a momentum to make our gradient more stable Then we can write

```
cache = decay_rate * cache + (1 - decay_rate) * dx**2
**m = beta1*m + (1-beta1)*dx**  [beta1 =momentum parameter in the doc ]
x += - learning_rate * dx / (np.sqrt(cache) + eps)
```

Now you can see here if we keep beta1 = o Then it's rms_prop without the momentum .

**Then Basics of ADAM**

In [cs-231 Andrej Karpathy](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/) has initially described the adam like this

> Adam is a recently proposed update that looks a bit like RMSProp with
>   momentum

**So yes ! Then what makes this difference from the rms_prop with momentum ?**

```
m = beta1*m + (1-beta1)*dx
v = beta2*v + (1-beta2)*(dx**2)
**x += - learning_rate * m / (np.sqrt(v) + eps)**
```

He again mentioned in the updating equation **m , v are more smooth** .

So the difference from the rms_prop is the update is less noisy .

What makes this noise ?

Well in the initialization procedure we will initialize m and v as zero .

**m=v=0**

In order to reduce this initializing effect it's always to have some warm-up . So then equation is like

```
m = beta1*m + (1-beta1)*dx          beta1 -o.9 beta2-0.999
**mt = m / (1-beta1**t)**
v = beta2*v + (1-beta2)*(dx**2)
**vt = v / (1-beta2**t)**
x += - learning_rate * mt / (np.sqrt(vt) + eps)
```

Now we run this for few iterations . Clearly pay attention to the bold lines  , you can see when t is increasing (iteration number)  following thing happen to the mt ,

**mt = m**