# What is the default learningRate and decay of the adam optimizer

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

According to [the documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.9.0/#train.adam), the learningRate is optionnal in the adam optimizer.

If non set what is the default learningRate ?

Is it computed dynamically according to the variables values ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: Confusion regarding the adam optimizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37842913/tensorflow-confusion-regarding-the-adam-optimizer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-core/blob/v0.13.0/src/optimizers/optimizer_constructors.ts#L130-L134) which is linked to on the [doc page](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#train.adam), the default values are (currently):

```
learningRate = 0.001
beta1 = 0.9
beta2 = 0.999
```